# Calculating SQL RunningTotal column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:
[image]

I want RunningTotal column should be calculated as like:
Balance=Deposit+Balance and Withdraw-Balance on each row for example I want RunningTotal table must be like this:

```
    AccountNo       Deposit   Withdraw    RunningTotal
---------------    --------    --------    --------------
    2014002         1000         0         1000
    305002            0         500        500
    50021           2500        100        2900
    54201           6000         0         8900
```

Help me!

Comment: Take a look at either the LAG window function, or the ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEEDING modifier for the SUM window function, if your sqlserver supports them. A question like this will undoubtedly have been asked before, so there are probably other good resources on SO to be had with a quick search for SQL SERVER RUNNING TOTAL.. welcome to SO!

Comment: Although your desired solution is vague, it sounds like you might be after a VIEW or a computed column?

Comment: Running total is meaningless unless you give us a column to order your records.  Is there a way to order?

Comment: Caius Jard has put more effort in this question than OP. Saying *Help me!* is of no use unless you clear the doubts of the volunteers trying to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way using `sum() over()` works from 2012. Considering you have an `id/date` column to order the results

```
select AccountNo, Deposit, Withdraw, 
       RunningTotal = sum(Deposit-Withdraw)over(order by id Rows between UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and current row )
from Yourtable
```

For older versions

```
select AccountNo, Deposit, Withdraw, 
       cs.RunningTotal
from Yourtable a
cross apply(select sum(Deposit-Withdraw)
            from Yourtable b 
            where a.id>=b.id) cs (RunningTotal)
```

- ### [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cce567/9)

Comment: Does the OP have an `id` column?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - yep added a note. There should be some column to order the result

Comment: You know what, broken an ordering strategy as it is, I think from the limited data example posted the ACCOUNT column might be what it's ordered by, in "number stored in a varchar" natural alphabetical sorting.. :/ pity the accountant!

Comment: @CaiusJard : There should be a date on which these transactions were made

Comment: There is, it just doesn't seem to be used.. see my edit to his question, to show the table data. The result asked for seems to be ORDER BY CAST(accountno AS VARCHAR), essentially :( - I suppose it could be ordered by chequeno which would be more logical, if it were always the same cheque book - it just can't be because there are deposits and withdrawals

Comment: @CaiusJard The `ChequeNo` columns looks like a possible candidate.

Comment: See my edit to comment above.. that would be similarly crazy, in my opinion, because there's no consistency there either.. How far do we go in fixing someone's broken logic? http://xyproblem.info for sure

Comment: @CaiusJard - Yeah there is one but useless as per the expected result. Let wait for OP's opinion here

Comment: If, on stackoverflow, you select one answer that better meets your needs than all others, click on the tick mark under the vote counter to mark that answer as the accepted one. If any other answers were helpful to you, taught you something or assisted you in reaching your goal, give them and upvote. If you ever need a reminder of when you should vote and which way, point to the vote/tick button for a while and read the tooltip. Good luck!

Comment: The 1st solution is good but the 2nd solution (using a correlated CROSS APPLY) is, by far the least efficient way to calculate a running total; note this article: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/61539/. More efficient pre-2012 solutions inclue the Quirky Update, a recursive CTE or even a cursor (cursor also not recomended).

Comment: @AlanBurstein - Agreed.. am little lazy to write a recursive CTE here, hope OP doesn't run it against a large table. Also *Quirky* update is not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Try a computed column in SQL Server, change the column `RunningTotal` to a computed column which calculates its value for each row based on `Deposit - Withdraw`. Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
    AccountNo VARCHAR(50),
    Deposit   NUMERIC(19,2),
    Withdraw  NUMERIC(19,2),  
    RunningTotal AS (Deposit - Withdraw)
)

INSERT INTO #temp (AccountNo, Deposit, Withdraw)
    SELECT '1234', 100, 50

SELECT * FROM #temp
```

Now the result will be like this

[image]

I'm adding 20 to the deposit and the `RunningTotal` will be automatically changed

```
UPDATE #temp 
SET Deposit = Deposit + 20

SELECT * FROM #temp
```

[image]

If you have multiple rows for each account and want to calculate the `RunningTotal` for each row separately (assuming that you have a primary key/ identity column on your table - like below)

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable
(
    SeqNo INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    AccountNo VARCHAR(50),
    Deposit NUMERIC(19,2),
    Withdraw NUMERIC(19,2),  
    RunningTotal AS (Deposit - Withdraw)
)
```

Create an UDF to calculate the value, like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_CalculateBalance
    (@AccountNo VARCHAR(50), @Id INT)
RETURNS NUMERIC(19,2)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RunningTotal NUMERIC(19,2)

    SELECT @RunningTotal = SUM(Deposit) - SUM(Withdraw) 
    FROM YourTable 
    WHERE AccountNo = @AccountNo 
      AND SeqNo <= @Id

    RETURN @RunningTotal
END
```

Now change the `RunningTotal` like this

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable
(
    SeqNo INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    AccountNo VARCHAR(50),
    Deposit NUMERIC(19,2),
    Withdraw NUMERIC(19,2),  
    RunningTotal AS (dbo.fn_CalculateBalance(AccountNo, SeqNo))
)
```

Or if you want to use the `Date` column instead on the `SeqNo` (identity column). Change the UDF to replace the check for `SeqNo` with the `Date` column.

When you look at the messages you can see the message "1 row(s) affected" multiple times. That's because you have this computed column and pass the date value in the computed column.

Comment: How does this running total bring in values from other rows? I understood it that he wants a report like a bank statement, where this row's total depeands on the previous row's total, plus deposits, minus withdrawals

Comment: @CaiusJard I have added one more solution to my answer

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh - Still logic is wonrg, remove the `AccountNo` filter

Comment: Does this solution work if the table is updated? (I've never used UDF in this way)

Comment: @CaiusJard - It will. But it will be really slow on large tables

Comment: I does not have Identity column in my table

Comment: Frying pan into the fire!

Comment: This solution will be horrifically slow on large data sets. Your method is also known as a triangle join, similar to the solution above. Here's a good article about triangle joins.